# how to make the fonts list works in the JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, itemlistener

I tried many things and i only been able to put the fonts on the list but how can i make them works when they are selected?

this is my code

```
    package textModifier;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class javaTextEditor extends JComboBox implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("A text modifier frame - Assignment 1");      
    Border layout = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter Message:");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Select Font:");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel();

    JTextField text = new JTextField("UIPG - Assignment 1");

    JComboBox fonts;

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    String fontName[] = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    Vector vector = new Vector();

    ButtonGroup radio = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton red = new JRadioButton("Red");
    JRadioButton green = new JRadioButton("Green");
    JRadioButton blue = new JRadioButton("Blue");

    JCheckBox Capitalized, Bold, Italic;

    JButton Left, Center, Right;

    public void ui(){

        for (int i = 1; i < fontName.length; i++)
            vector.addElement(fontName[i]);

        fonts = new JComboBox(vector); // wwwwqput the font names on the ComboBox

        Capitalized = new JCheckBox("Capitalized");
        Bold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        Italic = new JCheckBox("Italic");

        Left = new JButton("Left");
        Center = new JButton("Center");
        Right = new JButton("Right");

        radio.add(red);
        radio.add(green);
        radio.add(blue);

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(fonts);

        panel3.add(red);
        panel3.add(green);
        panel3.add(blue);

        panel2.add(Capitalized);
        panel2.add(Bold);
        panel2.add(Italic);

        panel4.add(Left);
        panel4.add(Center);
        panel4.add(Right);

        panel5.setBorder(layout);
        panel5.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panel5.add(label3);

        Left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == Left)
                    label3.setLocation(10, 8);


            }
        });

        Center.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == Center)
                    label3.setLocation(245, 8);

            }
        });

        Right.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == Right)
                    label3.setLocation(480, 8);

            }
        });
        red.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(red.isSelected())
                label3.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
        });

        green.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(green.isSelected())
                label3.setForeground(Color.green);
            }
        });


        blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(blue.isSelected())
                    label3.setForeground(Color.blue);
            }
        });

        text.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String str = text.getText();
                label3.setText(str);

            }
        });

        panel5.add(label3);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel3, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel4.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel4);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel5);

        Bold.addItemListener(this);
        Italic.addItemListener(this);
        Capitalized.addItemListener(this);


    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}



    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Font f = null;

        if(Bold.isSelected() && Italic.isSelected() && Capitalized.isSelected()){
            f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
            label3.setText(label3.getText().toUpperCase());
        }
        else if(Bold.isSelected())
            f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        else if(Italic.isSelected())
            f = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        else if(Capitalized.isSelected())
            label3.setText(label3.getText().toUpperCase());
        else{
            f = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        }
        label3.setFont(f);
    }

}
```

what should i write in the ActionListener that can make the fonts works?

Comment: You haven't added `ItemListener` or `ActionListener` on `JComboBox`.

Comment: I don't see the listener for the combobox. Is your attempt at this task posted in the code above?

Comment: Add `fonts.addItemListener(this);` in your code in the end and try again.

Comment: Try using fonts.getSelectedItem(), this will return null if nothing is selected or a Font object. You will need to cSt the result from this method to a Font

Comment: Instead of `fonts.getSelectedItem()` use `fonts.getSelectedIndex()` that returns -1 if nothing selected.

Comment: Use `ActionListener` instead of `ItemListener` for `JComboBox`

Comment: `public class javaTextEditor extends JComboBox..` Why extend `JComboBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't posted you attempt at this (just an empty method), I'll try and point you in the right direction.

First this you should do is take a look at the [Font API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html). There you'll see methods like

- [`public String getFamily()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getFamily%28%29)
- [`public int getSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getSize%28%29)
- [`public int getStyle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getStyle%28%29)

So in your listener, first get the font of whatever it is you want to change the font on.

```
Font font = label.getFont();
```

Then use the getters above to get the values and create/set a new font based of the new value recieved from the combo box. Something like

```
String family = (String)combobox.getSelectedItem();
Font font = label.getFont();
int size = font.getSize();
int style = font.getStyle();
label.setFont(new Font(family, size, style));
```

You can use the same technique for your listeners for your check boxes also, since I see you are hard coding the family.

---

**Side Notes:**

- Use java naming convention - variables begin with lower case letters `Bold` → `bold`
- Also I have absolutely no idea why your class is extending JComboBox. Looks like a completely faulty design